# RestEasy + Jackson 2 custom deserialization

Tags: web-services, resteasy, jackson2

I am coding a client for a webservice that the response looks something like:

```
{
   "succeed": true,
   "code": 2000,
   "pagination": {
       "items": [
           {
             "id": 17694,
             ...
           },
           {
              "id": 17695,
             ...
           }
         ],
         "count": 2,
         "offset": 0
     },
     "message": "Petición satisfactoria."
 }
```

The response always return a list of one type per request, my problem is that *items* array can be of different types, for example:

```
{
    "id", 1,
    "otherProperty" : "Foo",
    ...
}
```

or

```
{
    "id", 1,
    "anotherProperty" : "Foo",
     ...
}
```

I tryed to map that response to a Java class with something like:

```
public class WsResponse {
    private WsPagination<?> pagination;
    private boolean succeed;
    ...
}
```

Where WsPagination has:

```
public class WsPagination <T> {
    List<T> items;
    int count;
    int offset;
    ...
}
```

And it works, but the List of *items* is returned as java.util.LinkedHashMap and i want that RestEasyClient serialize as the correct class

Example:

```
public class Foo {
     Long id;
     String otherProperty;
}
```

And

```
public class Bar {
   Long id;
   String anotherProperty;
}
```

I tryed to register a custom JsonDeserializer for type WsPagination but it is not called, don't know why.

```
 Class<?> clazz = getRequestType();
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("myModule",
            new Version(1, 0, 0, "", "", ""));

    module.addDeserializer(WsPagination.class, new WsPaginationDeserializer(clazz));
    mapper.registerModule(module);


    ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
            .register(module)
            .register(new ClientRequestFilter() {

                @Override
                public void filter(ClientRequestContext context)
                        throws IOException {
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entrySet : headers
                            .entrySet()) {
                        String key = entrySet.getKey();
                        String value = entrySet.getValue();
                        context.getHeaders().add(key, value);
                    }
                }
            }).build();
```

the WsPaginationDeserializer class:

```
 public class WsPaginationDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<WsPagination> {

    Class<?> clazz;

    /**
     * Constructs a new instance of type FooTest.WsPaginationDeserializer
     */
    public WsPaginationDeserializer(Class<?> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public WsPagination deserialize(JsonParser arg0,
            DeserializationContext arg1)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // method not called
        throw new IOException("Deserialize here!!");
    }


}
```

How can i get the list of items fullfilled with the correct type.

Thank you.

EDIT 14/11/2017

As a work arround get those java.util.LinkedHashMap and the convert them to the corresponding model:

```
if(path.equals("somePath")){
     if((result = resp.getResult()) != null){
           Object items = null;
           if((items = result.getItems()) != null){
           // here items are a list of java.util.LinkedHashMap, so then try to convert them to the model we need for the "somePath"
           List models = mapper.convertValue(items, new TypeReference<List<WsComprobante>>() {});
           // now re assing the list of WsComprobante again to the result list of items
           result.setItems(models);
     }
                    }
                }
```

Hope this help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that jackson doesn't know which class it is suposed to use when deserializing your items.

One way to prevent this is to create a custom WSResponse class for each item type:

```
public class WsResponse<T> {
    private WsPagination<T> pagination;
    private boolean succeed;
    ...
}

public class WsPagination <T> {
    List<T> items;
    int count;
    int offset;
    ...
}

public class FooResponse extends WsResponse<Foo>{}
public class BarResponse extends WSResponse<Bar>{}
```

Comment: Those are classes shared from another project and i need to use them. What i did: 
    if(path.equals("timbrado")){
                        if((result = resp.getResult()) != null){
                            Object items = null;
                            if((items = result.getItems()) != null){
                                List models = mapper.convertValue(items, new 
  TypeReference<List<WsComprobante>>() {});
                                result.setItems(models);
                            }
                        }
                    }